# Ionic Mobile App Development With Live Reload Native

Tags: ios, angular, ionic7

Is there a way to use live-reload in Ionic when developing a mobile app (iOS, Android), without going to a url in the browser? The whole idea of developing a mobile app is NOT to be run in a browser on the device but as a proper mobile app.

I tried the "serve" command and the "Live Reload" configuration in the VS Code extension. I was expecting to run the app natively instead of in a browser, change something in the src, and have the application "reload"